# Performance of Singleton Controllers in fastapi

Tags: python, rest, singleton, fastapi

I am having trouble troubleshooting a performance bottleneck in one of my APIs and I have a theory that I need somebody with deeper knowledge of Python to validate for me.

I have a fastapi web service and a nodejs web service deployed on AWS. The node.js api is performing perfeclty under heavier loads, multiple concurrent requests taking same amount of time to be served.

My fastapi service however, is performing absurdly. If I make two requests concurrently, only one is served while the other has to wait for the first to be finished, hence the response time for the second request is twice as long as the first one.

My theory is that I am using Singleton pattern to instantiate the controller after a request comes to a route and the object already being in use and locked is causing the second request to wait until the first is resolved. Could this be it or am I missing something very obvious here? 2 concurrent requests should absolutely not be a problem for any type of web server.

Comment: How are you running your FastAPI instances? Are you using multiple workers? Are you using async endpoint definitions in your FastAPI controllers - and are you then actually using async compatible calls inside those endpoints?

Comment: this is the command im using to run fast api web: uvicorn application:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000

all endpoints are async, but im not sure what it would mean for the calls inside the endpoints to be async compatible. Can you point me to a reference to understand it better please? @Mats

Comment: If you've defined your endpoints as async, it also assumes that anything you do inside those endpoints are async compatible - i.e. that you can `await` the result of the functions you call. If there are no `await` calls, then there is nowhere that the coroutine can give up time to be processed by other coroutines. You can change your endpoint definition to not be async to have FastAPI run it in a threadpool instead.